# How to find the antiderivative of this function?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I want to integrate this function:

$$\int\dfrac{x^2}{e^x-1}dx$$
I used integration by parts formula to integrate it.
However I have reached somewhere where I got something like this:

$$\int\dfrac{e^xx^3}{(e^x-1)^2}dx$$

Now I cannot go further. Is there any way I can solve this problem from here? Thank you!!

Comment: There is no reason to think this has an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: You may want to look at this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html

Comment: @ André Nicolas : I came to know it will involve the polylog fundtion. However i need to find this integration from limit a to infinity. What can be other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

This has no elementary antiderivative. This involves [polylogarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%7D%7Be%5Ex-1%7D). As TylerHG also pointed out, you may want to check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Definition).

If so inclined, then you could write the denominator $e^x - 1 = -1 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: a series expansion is just the right tool for the job!

Comment: thank you for your suggestions really appreciate  !! I will try that .

Comment: @Bibek did you choose the -8 answer over mine? :|

Comment: @Bclc sorry i press the wrong option , actually i want to press the option that says the answer is not useful but my mistake :( !! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

$\int\dfrac{x^2}{e^x-1}dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{B_nx^{n+1}}{n!}dx$ (with the formula in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function)

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{B_nx^{n+2}}{n!(n+2)}+C$